# AngularJS JSON HTML Character encoding

Tags: angularjs, json, encoding, html-sanitizing

I'm new to JS/AngularJS (using V1.3.0)

I am making an API call using WP API (wordpress api) to return JSON in Angular. The app is almost working as I want, but I use a value selected from one JSON call to filter another JSON file using a ng-repeat. It is wokring as should apart from when the value has a special character in (ampersand, apostrophe, full stop, foreign letter etc) I'm guessing I need to parse/sanatize the JSON first? Here is an example of the characters being sent:

```
Anderson&#039;s
COMME DES GAR\u00c7ONS
DOLCE &amp; GABBANA
```

I use this in my factory to get brands:

```
function getBrands(arg) {
  return ($http.get(url + 'designers?filter[meta_key]=alpha&filter[meta_value]=' + arg + '&filter[posts_per_page]=200').then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeBrand = function(){
    wpFactory.getBrands($scope.radioValue).then(function (succ) {
    $scope.brands = succ;
    angular.forEach(succ, function(value, index) {
        $scope.setUrlForImage(index, value.featured_image);
    });
    }, function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
});
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-init="my = {Variable: ''}" >

    <div ng-repeat="myVar in brands" ng-init="my.Variable=myVar" >
    </div>
    <ul class="media-list">
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { acf: { store_brands: my.Variable.title.rendered } }">
         <div class="media-body">
              <a href="{{post.acf.store_url}}" target="_blank">
                <h4 class="media-heading">{{post.title.rendered}}</h4>
              </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have seen ng-bind-html used, but how do I pre format the JSON for use in ng-repeat and as dynamic filter values?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide your HTML code as well.

Comment: I've added the html, basically trying to grab a value from brands JSON and filter against and value in posts JSON. Working apart from when special characters are involved..

Comment: It seems it problem related to your your JSON response, not on angular front.

Comment: So the data should be sent differently from WordPress API rather than changed by angular?